# Python list comprehension filtering with tuples (containing integers as strings)

Tags: python, string, list, tuples, list-comprehension

I am trying to filter the following list: 
`tuple = [('7:29', 0.5), ('99:2', 0.35714285714285715), ('10:2', 0.35714285714285715)]` using list comprehension, filtering based on the first elements from the tuples between the character ':'.
For example: `filter = [7, 99]`, thus the result would be: `new_tuple = [('7:29', 0.5), ('99:2', 0.35714285714285715)]`.

I tried the following solution:

```
filter_string = [str(item) for item in filter]
tuple_filtered = [(x,y) for (x,y) in tuples if x in filter]
```

but it returns an empty list and I don't have any idea how to fix it.
Can somebody please help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[(x,y) for (x,y) in tuples if  str(x.split(":")[0]) in filter_string ]
```

Equivalently:

```
op = []
for (x,y) in tuples :
    if str(x.split(":")[0]) in filter_string:
        op.append((x,y))
```

Comment: Happy to help :) I find list comprehension can get very hairy very quickly

Comment: Since you never use `y`, `[t for t in tuples if str(t[0].split(...) in filter_string]` might be simpler.

Answer (score 4):

First when you apply this line:

```
filter_string = [str(item) for item in filter]
```

You apply str() function over a tuple object - making all the tuple in to a string.
for example - `str(('99:2', 0.35714285714285715))` --> `'(\\'99:2\\', 0.35714285714285715)'`
Which in my sense just make it harder to parse.

Second, `tuple` is a saved name in python - **do not use it and run it over**!
it can cause very annoying bugs later on.

Finally, you can look at a tuple as a fixed size array which is indexed, which mean you can address the first element (that you want to filter by)

Something like that:

```
my_tuples = [('7:29', 0.5), ('99:2', 0.35714285714285715), ('10:2', 0.35714285714285715)]
my_filter = [7, 99]
filtered_list =  [t for t in my_tuples if int(t[0].split(':')[0]) 
                  in my_filter]
```